# @ViewChild || native element Issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I am trying to access a HTML div using @ViewChild based on a JavaScript object as shown below:

```
<div class="main-div">
<gs-configuration-tabs ></gs-configuration-tabs>
<div class="content-div">
        <div class="pipelines" *ngFor = "let pipeline of pipelineData; let i = index">
            <div class="pipeline-block oxyclass" *ngIf ="pipeline?.oxy" #oxyBlock>
                <button class="pill" *ngIf = "pipeline?.oxy?.status == 'active'">Active</button>
                {{pipeline?.oxy?.name}}
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**TypeScript Code:**

```
@ViewChild('oxyBlock', {static: false}) oxyBlock: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('topicBlock', {static: false}) topicBlock: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('halBlock', {static: false}) halBlock: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("After View Init::",this.oxyBlock,this.halBlock);
    this.pipelineData.forEach(function(item) {
      console.log("Item data is::",item.oxy.role);
      if (item)
      {
        if (item.oxy.role == 'Publisher')
        {
          console.log('Oxy to HAL');
          const Line1 = new LeaderLine(this.oxyBlock.nativeElement,this.topicBlock.nativeElement);
          const Line2 = new LeaderLine(this.topicBlock.nativeElement,this.halBlock.nativeElement);
        }
        else{
          console.log('HAL to Oxy');
          const Line1 = new LeaderLine(this.halBlock.nativeElement,this.topicBlock.nativeElement);
          const Line2 = new LeaderLine(this.topicBlock.nativeElement,this.oxyBlock.nativeElement);
        }
      }
    });
    
    // const Line1 = new LeaderLine(this.oxyBlock.nativeElement,this.topicBlock.nativeElement);
    // const Line2 = new LeaderLine(this.topicBlock.nativeElement,this.halBlock.nativeElement);
  }
```

I have used leader-line to draw arrows between divs rendered on the basis of JavaScript Object. Outside the foreach loop everything works fine. But, inside the loop i am facing below error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'oxyBlock' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your callback to `forEach()` you use `this`. You think it refers to the component but it does not. You can easily see this if you log `this` to the console. Or you can use a debugger and set a breakpoint inside your callback.

You need to use an *arrow function* to correctly capture the value of `this`.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.pipelineData.forEach(item => {
```